# Flying Saucer(xhtmlrenderer) word-split

Tags: xhtmlrenderer, flying-saucer

I am getting a bug with Flying Saucer(xhtmlrenderer) where a word at the end of a line gets split across two lines, eg. thinking gets split into thin king, with king appearing at the beginning of the following line. This is very puzzling since the split does not seem to follow a pattern and seems to happen rarely and randomly e.g. 1 in every 20 pdfs generated.

Has anyone else, who has used Flying Saucer, encountered a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted. Answer available at http://abhirampal.com/2012/04/18/pdf-document-word-split-using-flying-saucerxhtml-renderer/